# Dexgaurd Configuration for a file

Tags: android, proguard, ical4j, dexguard

I am using ical4j.jar for processing iCal in that we need to add a ical4j.properties file inside src folder for additional options. If i add outside SRC it not taking.

If i enabled dexgaurd then ical4j.properties is removed by dexgaurd.

I need to add that file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you add your properties file to the libs directory in your project, DexGuard should automatically include it in the output apk.

Comment: but i want it in src folder